# Illegal string offset. Can't get a child from JSON multi level file

Tags: php, json

Here's my JSON file:

```
{
 "user": {

  "id": "2.8.388387",

  "category": "posts",

  "json_metadata": {

     "tags": [

        "new",

     ],

     "image": [

        "https://s32.postimg.org/4twcn4yrp/13918652_1345543288792650_1255274463_o.gif"

     ]

  }

 }
}
```

And PHP:

```
$json = json_decode($content, true);


foreach($json as $i){

  $id = $i['id'];
  $category = $i['category'];
  $image = $i['json_metadata']['image'];

  echo $id;
  echo $category;
  echo $image;
}
```

Echo $id and $category works just fine. However, $image errors:
*Warning: Illegal string offset 'image'*

Any ideas what do I miss?

Comment: Try $i['json_metadata']['image'][0];

Comment: Please show full structure of json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json_metadata is array within loop, so you just need to get data from array as we do in array. it's simple...This will work now foreach loop. you can also print json_metadata array in loop.

```
$content = '{
    "user": {
        "id": "example glossary",
        "category": "example glossary",
        "json_metadata": {
            "tags": ["new"],
            "image": [
                "https://s32.postimg.org/4twcn4yrp/13918652_1345543288792650_1255274463_o.gif"
            ]
        }
    }
}';
$json = json_decode($content, true);
foreach ($json as $i) {
    $id = $i['id'];
    $category = $i['category'];
    $image = $i['json_metadata']['image'][0];

    echo $id;
    echo $category;
    echo $image;
}
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answers to help future visitors.

Comment: json_metadata is array within loop, so you just need to get data from array  as we do in array. it's simple...This will work now foreach loop. you can also print json_metadata array in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$content = '{
              "user": {
                  "id": "example glossary",
                  "category": "example glossary",
                  "json_metadata": {
                      "tags": ["new"],
                      "image": [
                        "https://s32.postimg.org/4twcn4yrp/13918652_1345543288792650_1255274463_o.gif"
                      ]
                  }
              }
            }';
$json = json_decode($content, true);
print_r($json['user']['json_metadata']['image'][0]);
```

You will got:

https://s32.postimg.org/4twcn4yrp/13918652_1345543288792650_1255274463_o.gif